# Print Pages in Certain Order

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I have a code that is running well but looks kind of "not right", just out of curiosity, is there a better way I can print pages 1,6,2,7,3,8,4,9,5 in this order?

```
Sub PrntPgs()
ActiveSheet.PrintOut 1, 1, 1
ActiveSheet.PrintOut 6, 6, 1
ActiveSheet.PrintOut 2, 2, 1
ActiveSheet.PrintOut 7, 7, 1
ActiveSheet.PrintOut 3, 3, 1
ActiveSheet.PrintOut 8, 8, 1
ActiveSheet.PrintOut 4, 4, 1
ActiveSheet.PrintOut 9, 9, 1
ActiveSheet.PrintOut 5, 5, 1
End Sub
```

Any Help is appreciated

Nick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your page numbers in an array and use a loop

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PrntPgs()
    Dim PageList() As Variant
    PageList = Array(1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9, 5)

    Dim PageNo As Variant
    For Each PageNo In PageList
        ActiveSheet.PrintOut PageNo, PageNo, 1
    Next PageNo
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy, this is much better. I never thought of the Array List.